# Overloading doesn't work with curry function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get return type based on exact string from parameter.

Here is what I have so far (without curring):

```
type Simple = {
  (side: 'left'): boolean;
  (side: 'right'): number;
};

const simple: Simple = (side: 'left' | 'right') =>
  (side === 'left' ? random([true]) : random([1])) as boolean & number;

const simpleLeft = simple('left'); // boolean ✔️
const simpleRight = simple('right'); // number ✔️
```

Then I just add curring and it doesn't work anymore

```
type Hard = {
  (): (side: 'left') => boolean;
  (): (side: 'right') => number;
};

const hard: Hard = () => (side: 'left' | 'right') =>
  (side === 'left' ? random([true]) : random([1])) as boolean & number;

const hardLeft = hard()('left'); // boolean ✔️
const hardRight = hard()('right'); // boolean ❌
```

random function is there to just get generic type like `boolean` instead of `false` or `true`

```
const random = <T>(array: T[]) =>
  array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)] as T;
```

Code above is just an example demonstrating problem, I can't just not use curring because it is a part of big code base

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you need currying here. But if you want this to compile correctly you need to put the function overload inside the first function signature.

```
type Hard = {
  (): {
    (side: 'left'): boolean;
    (side: 'right'): number;
  }  
};
```

Now the compiler can decide which overload to choose based on the input of the second function.

```
const hardLeft = hard()('left'); // boolean ✔️
const hardRight = hard()('right'); // number ✔️
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=48&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgJwCZQLxQN4CgpQBQCUAXJjrvgM4CWSEJA5ADYQBmw9xUARgPY-NwAdgG4yuPNVoMEVAOYALdp0EBXALZcICUbgC%20uLLtFYAxj0EVgUeYiQl4yNPgJoAfJRp0oTVuygAfbxkFJTcyCU80VHQfNnooAH4oBCEkHjU8AG1gBBUIAF0XEhTBNIzMgEZClzgKbj4BQSgAMihVDS1jMwsrG2QAGV8nPqRCPFilYSgAemn6-gghKEAUckB4P9NzS2tbACU5RWHbMfpgxQ4p2bb1TQQV1aA)

Comment: I know it was not directly asked in a question, but would it be possible to remove `as boolean & number` part?

Comment: I would say no. It's always hard to type the implementations of function overloads correctly. Type assertions to make TypeScript happy are almost always needed.

Answer (score 1):

That type `Hard` just looks like an invalid function overload to me. When evaluating `hard()`, there is no way for the compiler to infer which of the two signatures you're referring to.

I don't know if it fits your needs, but you could use a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) with a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```
type Hard = {
  (): <T extends 'left' | 'right'>(side: T)
    => T extends 'left' ? boolean :
       T extends 'right' ? number : never;
};

const hard: Hard = () => (side: 'left' | 'right') =>
  (side === 'left' ? random([true]) : random([1])) as boolean & number;

const hardLeft = hard()('left'); // boolean ✔️
const hardRight = hard()('right'); // number ✔️

const random = <T>(array: T[]) =>
  array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)] as T;
```

Comment: I know it was not directly asked in a question, but would it be possible to remove `as boolean & number` part?